# How to make Image page viewer for images swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uipageviewcontroller

I wanna display a couple of images from the assets folders, into my application. so I wanna make a page view.

First, images will be inside collection view, then on click, the image will be full screen. Then the user can slide between the images by swiping right and left as shown in the following photo:

[image: Description for required lib or sample]

I found this tutorial:

[PhotosGalleryApp](https://github.com/TDAbboud/PhotosGalleryApp)

**Updated:**

I have this in my storyboard:

[image]

Now in `GaleryViewController` I show the images in cells

when user click on it, I open the image in fullscreen in `PhotoViewController`.

> PhotoViewController.swift :

```
import UIKit

class PhotoViewController: UIViewController{


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var index: Int = 0;
var pageViewController : UIPageViewController?

@IBAction func btnCancelClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true);
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    initUI();
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true;
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true;
    displayPhoto()
}

func initUI() -> Void {
//        pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
//        pageViewController!.dataSource = self
}

func displayPhoto() {
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: Constants.Statics.images[index])
}
```

I have the images in static structure so i can access them anywhere:

```
class Constants {

    struct Statics {
        static let images = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","7.jpg","8.jpg"]
    }
}
```

My problem is: I want to add the feature that allow me to swipe between pictures inside the `PhotoViewController`.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see in any part of your code that you have set the dataSource and delegate of the PageViewController and set the ViewController to implements the protocols UIPageViewControllerDelegate neither UIPageViewControllerDataSource nad without this you can't make a Swipe of any type.

Comment: @VictorSigler thats what i was trying to find out, Actually i started swift after 3 years of android development, there i used Pager to implement the same thing, thank you for the help

Comment: @VictorSigler You may put it as an answer i will accept it for the question

Comment: I going to update my answer to handle the slideShow , don't worry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do one of the following two things to achieve your goal :

1. Make a modal segue of the cell to the next `UICollectionViewController` where the images are showed in full screen, and in the `prepareForSegue` pass all the data (images) you need to show and where exactly you are in this moment (`indexOfImage`).
2. You can watch the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and then pass all the data to one instance of the next `UICollectionViewController` you want to show with the `presentViewController` func.

But it's very important that in the next `UICollectionViewController` you have set `pageEnabled = true` in code or in the Interface Builder (I though is much easy to do.)

> UPDATE:

Very good tutorials on how to make a slide show of images using an `UIScrollView` or an `UICollectionView` :

- [How To Use UIScrollView to Scroll and Zoom Content](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content)
- [Creating a Paged Photo Gallery With a UICollectionView](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/)

I hope this help you.

Comment: my main problem is to perform the swipe left and right actions to show the next and previous picture, all other things work fine for me

Comment: @you have set `pageEnabled = true` in the `UICollectionView` ? Please share more code then.

Comment: @MBH I'm put some very good tutorials on how to achieve what do you want, because I'm writing a tutorial on how to do it in Swift but it has not been completed yet, I'll update the answer when I finish it. I hope this help you

Comment: well this is exactly what i really want, THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @VictorSigler..  Can u explain me some more detail to achieve this in swift